# How to get m3u8 link from live streaming link

Tags: php, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I want to get the m3u8 link which loaded after playing video. From the website https://www.firstonetv.eu. It's unavailable in HTML source code. Now I can see it on network tab in Chrome. Here is the image:
[Network tab snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjdyI.png)
But I want to get it through PHP.Also, a javascirpt solution is appreciated. How could I get the m3u8 link?

Answer (score 1):

Every site is different.  You would have to reverse engineer their site to figure out how it's getting the URL to the HLS playlist.

Alternatively, a generic solution could be implemented by writing a browser extension to look for `application/x-mpegURL` in the content type headers in HTTP responses... and when you find one, log it or open it elsewhere.  Keep in mind that the video you get could be anything... ads and such.

What you should do instead though is contact the site and ask for access to their API or a better proper way to do this.  You *do* have their permission, right?